# What's the mathmatics formula in robot_localization

Tags: navigation, robot-localization

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Tom/all:
I'm wondering what the mathmatics formula in ekf.cpp file is. It's the core of EKF. But I got confused when looking through those code. Can somebody enlighten it to me? Thank you so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/264174/what%27s-the-mathmatics-formula-in-robot_localization/) by [DaDaLee](https://answers.ros.org/users/30176/dadalee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 113 on 2017-06-19

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-06-20**:
What code are you referring to? Do you have a link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can read [this paper](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_localization?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=robot_localization_ias13_revised.pdf) from the authors of the package. But even there it's a bit unclear what the exact state update is. [This question](http://answers.ros.org/question/221837/robot_localization-ekf-internal-motion-model/) contains some details too.

As I understand it they assume a second order model for all calculations and estimate the velocity+acceleration from measurements, they then use the standard EKF update. But I haven't been able to find details on how these motion model parameters are estimated.

---

Originally posted by [linusnie](https://answers.ros.org/users/30863/linusnie/) with karma: 98 on 2017-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0